# Compare current and previous Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring-Data and hibernate.

I wanted to compare new value, but the object passed as the method param is the same as the one I got from DB.
For my entity I created a listener.

```
@EntityListeners(MyListener.class)
public class MyClass{
```

My listener has hot @PreUpdate method

```
@PreUpdate
private void beforeAnyUpdate(MyClass newMyClass) {
     MyClassRepo repo = (MyClassRepo )
            BeanUtility.getBean("myClassRepo");
    Optional<MyClass > previousEntity= repo .findById(newMyClass.getId());



    System.out.println("previous : " + newMyClass.toString());
    System.out.println("current : " + previousEntity.get().toString());
```

and well... I get the same object. No idea why as I used pre update not post update.

```
previous : MyClass(id=1, variable1=test, variable2=test change)
current : MyClass(id=1, variable1=test, variable2=test change)
```

No idea what is going one, could someone advice me how to get both objects?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter in what lifecycle you are in. You can't access a "previous value" this way, because there is only ever one object associated to an entity manager for that id. If you want to access the previous state, you can use a Hibernate Interceptor and provide a custom `onFlushDirty` method where you can access the previous and current state.

Comment: How can I register such interceptor? I cannot find it anywhere, the only information contains 'HandlerInterceptor', while I created hibernate interceptor which extends EmptyInterceptor

Comment: There are plenty of articles online about this. For example this one here: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-interceptor